# PHP Recaptcha Form only Works with IP Address instead of www.google.com

Tags: php, recaptcha

As mentioned in the title. My recaptcha form only works if I change this:

```
define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", "www.google.com");
```

to this:

```
define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", "74.125.236.178");
```

I am using [myhosting.com](http://myhosting.com) vps linux server. Any idea why it doesn't work with [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix to this problem is,

```
//line 40 in recpatchalib.php and replace:
define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", "api-verify.recaptcha.net");

// With this:
define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", gethostbyname('api-verify.recaptcha.net'));
```

Try it.

Got from [Issues](http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/issues/detail?id=26) page.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Here is the entire code. I think it has been updated to check Google now. Is that my problem? `define("RECAPTCHA_API_SERVER", "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api");
define("RECAPTCHA_API_SECURE_SERVER", "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api");
define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", gethostbyname('www.google.com'));`

Comment: There is an another option too.... Please check to make sure /etc/ 
resolv.conf has read permissions for apache....

Comment: I just had them check that for me and this was the output. `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 52 Dec 20 23:55 /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: They finally fixed it!! This is what they said. Your hostname (my host name) could not be
resolved to an IP address. This means that /etc/hosts is not set up
correctly, and/or there is no dns entry for
(my host name)